# Press e to execute the program C++

Tags: c++

i have made a Min Max calculator that shows you the minimum, the maximum and how many numbers you have tiped in. Now i want that it executes the program by pressing 'e', so if you are done with typing in your numbers you press 'e' to execute the program and to show the results. Please keep it simple because its a school project. (I know that its in german)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float Ein, Min, Max, Anz, Ges;
    char Noch, Enter;
    Anz = 0;
    Ges = 0;
    do
    {
        cout << "Zum Bestaetigen --> e druecken" << endl;
        do
        {
            cout << "Eingabe: "; cin >> Ein || cin >> Enter;
            if (Min >= Ein)
            {
                Min = Ein;
            }
            if (Max <= Ein)
            {
                Max = Ein;
            }
            Anz = Anz + 1;
        } while (Enter != 'e');
        cout << "Anzahl, Maximum und Minimum " << Anz << " " << Max << " " 
<< Min << endl;
        cout << "Programm erneut ausfuehren? --> j: "; cin >> Noch;
    } while (Noch == 'j');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no standard c++ mechanism to detect individual key strokes.

Comment: If you are assuming that `cin >> Ein || cin >> Enter` will put a single user input into either `Ein` or `Enter` based on the input, you are mistaken. Due to operator short circuiting, you will accept an input, attempt to write it to `Ein`. If that failed, you will attempt to get an input again, put it in `Enter`, but fail because your stream is already in a failed state and hasn't been cleared. As far as I can tell, the present code will never write to `Enter`.

Answer (score 0):

|| is **logical or**, it means it is used in logical expressions, let's simplify that it's used in **if** statements, like

```
if(number == 5 || number == 7){
    do something
}
```

it means that 'do something' will get called if number is equal to 5 OR equal to 7

to check if user wants to finish inputting numbers you may use **Ctrl+Z** shortcut on windows to send EOF to input, proof of concept loks like:

```
int main(){
    int number;
    cout<<"enter any number you want or press Ctrl+Z to break\n";
    while(cin>>number){
        cout<<"you entered :"<<number<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"user has pressed ctrl+z (EOF detected)";
}
```

Comment: Note **Ctrl+Z** is disabled by default on Win10 cmd.exe unless the *Use Legacy console* option is selected [CTRL+Z does not generate EOF in Windows 10](http://proc-x.com/2017/06/ctrlz-does-not-generate-eof-in-windows-10/)

Comment: Also note that Ctrl+Z has another meaning in many Linux shells.

Comment: that's true, but I think it's simplest solution for school programming project without string -> number conversion or other advanced solutions

Comment: Now if i press ctrl+z the programm outputs Zahl:, so the while loop doesnt stops

Comment: you need to 'enter' ctrl+z like you enter numbers, and then press ENTER key

Comment: i press ctrl+z then it shows  ^Z and then i press enter